# How to fix a warning `Invalid frame dimension (negative or non-finite).`

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I'm trying to make a progress bar using a timer class.

When I make a small value like `0.05` in `every` parameter of `Timer.publish()` for a `width` of `Rectangle` I have a warning below:

> Invalid frame dimension (negative or non-finite).

How could I solve this problem?

---

Here are the codes:

TimeManager.swift

```
import SwiftUI

class TimeManager: ObservableObject {
    
    var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.05, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
}
```

ProgressBar.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProgressBar: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var timeManager:TimeManager
    
    @Binding var duration:Double
    @Binding var maxValue:Double
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width:CGFloat(self.duration / self.maxValue) * 150, height: 12)
            Text("value:\(CGFloat(self.duration / self.maxValue) )")

        }
            .onReceive( self.timeManager.timer) { _ in
                if self.duration > 0 {
                    self.duration -= 0.05
                }
            }
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var duration:Double = 8
    @State var maxValue:Double = 8
    
    var body: some View {
        ProgressBar(duration: $duration, maxValue: $maxValue)
    }

}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part can result in negative `duration` (e.g., when `duration` is `0.0001`):

```
if self.duration > 0 {
    self.duration -= 0.05
}
```

Because `duration` is later used in:

```
.frame(width: CGFloat(self.duration / self.maxValue) * 150, height: 12)
```

you get a negative width parameter.

---

A solution is to make sure the `duration` is never below 0.

Something like:

```
if self.duration > 0.05 {
    self.duration -= 0.05
} else {
    self.duration = 0
}
```

Comment: I would consider testing the subtraction against 0 before subtracting, i.e.: `if self.duration - 0.05 > 0`. You can then add an `else` to make duration 0. That way you don't lose a whole cycle

Answer (score 0):

`abs()` may gonna help , it works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30595618)